# When is then then clause from Promise.all() ran?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, collections, promise

I'm staring at this code snippet from http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

The code in particular is:

```
var files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    files.push(fs.writeFileAsync("file-" + i + ".txt", "", "utf-8"));
}
Promise.all(files).then(function() {
    console.log("all the files were created");
});
```

My question in particular is how does the compiler know to invoke the .then block once files is populated. What prevents the .then clause from being invoked when files is at a length of 10 or a length of 100.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have compiler

Comment: Because it's called `Promise.all` not `Promise.some`? Also, `files` is fully populated before we get to this line, with promises.

Comment: ah this helps a lot! thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When is then then clause from Promise.all() ran?

`Promise.all()` returns a new promise that has a specific behavior based on the array of promises that you passed to `Promise.all()`.

If any single promise in that array of promises rejects, then the `Promise.all()` promise will reject and will call the reject handler (if any) in it's `.then()`.

If/when all the promises you passed are resolved successfully, then the `Promise.all()` promise will resolve and it will call the resolve handler in the `.then()`.

> My question in particular is how does the compiler know to invoke the .then block once files is populated. What prevents the .then
>   clause from being invoked when files is at a length of 10 or a length
>   of 100.

`Promise.all()` does it's job by attaching a `.then()` handler to every single promise that you pass it and it then monitors their progress.   It maintains a counter to keep track of when every single promise you passed has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` creates and returns a new promise that wraps the provided array of promises. It will keep track of how many of the inner promises have resolved. Once all 100 have resolved, the wrapper promise resolves.